# base64.urlsafe_b64encode not correct if content contains extended ASCII characters

Tags: python, json, xml, python-2.7, base64

I've got a Python (2.7) client that talks to a PHP API. The Python client takes some UTF-8 encoded XML, converts it to JSON, then sends it to the API. There's other stuff going on but let's say that's what it does for brevity.

I'm finding the client fails to send data to the API properly if any of the strings from the XML contain extended ASCII characters like “,”,’ (typographer’s quotes), • (bullets), and just about anything else I can think of. If the XML data doesn't include extended characters it POSTs data to the API just fine, but it does include extended characters, the POST data is empty.

I know it's an encoding issue but have only been able to make sure that json.dumps isn't mangling the dict with all the unicode values in it.

The same problem occurs if the XML has the extended characters as HTML entities.

I know it's happening when the data gets passed through base64.urlsafe_b64encode. I know I'm missing something, but not sure where I'm going wrong.

Here's a simplifcation of what I've got going on:

```
import urllib3
import base64
import hmac
import json
import hashlib

def signString(string_to_sign, shared_secret):
        return hmac.new(shared_secret, string_to_sign, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

def send_to_api(action, payload):

    SHARED_SECRET = 'my_secret'

    json_payload = json.dumps(payload, ensure_ascii=False).strip(' \t\n\r')
    json_payload = json_payload.encode('utf-8')

    signature = signString(json_payload, SHARED_SECRET)
    encoded_signature = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature.strip(' \t\n\r'))
    encoded_payload = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(json_payload)

    #post = 'v=1.4.8&data={}'.format(encoded_payload)
    headers = { 'Action' : action, 'Signature': encoded_signature }
    pool = urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPSConnectionPool("mysite.com", maxsize=1, block=True, headers=headers, retries=10)
    request = pool.request('POST', '/api/api.v7.php', fields={'v': '1.4.6', 'data': encoded_payload})
    data = request.read()
    request.close()

##etc
```

Any ideas of what I could be missing?

**EDIT**

Here's the source dictionary I'm passing to send_to_api via the payload argument:

```
{'description': u'Before joining together as Fake Tears, Larissa Loyva and Elisha May Rembold were already established singers and songwriters in their own right. The former released two spectral albums under the name Kellarissa, toured the world as a live member of Destroyer and How to Dress Well, and played in past Mint Records acts P:ano and The Choir Practice; the latter leads the folk-rock band the Lost Lovers Brigade and is a member of Shimmering Stars. The pair first collaborated when Loyva joined the lineup of Lost Lovers, and honed their chemistry during a stint as backup vocalists in the funky local ensemble COOL TV.\nTheir current project dates back to 2012, when Loyva and Rembold got together as part of a larger ensemble. \u201cI thought I\u2019d make an all-woman supergroup,\u201d Loyva remembers. \u201cWe started with five, and then, after a couple of months and a couple of practices, we were down to two.'}
```

This is what it looks like after it's run through json.dumps, when it becomes a string:

```
{"description": "Before joining together as Fake Tears, Larissa Loyva and Elisha May Rembold were already established singers and songwriters in their own right. The former released two spectral albums under the name Kellarissa, toured the world as a live member of Destroyer and How to Dress Well, and played in past Mint Records acts P:ano and The Choir Practice; the latter leads the folk-rock band the Lost Lovers Brigade and is a member of Shimmering Stars. The pair first collaborated when Loyva joined the lineup of Lost Lovers, and honed their chemistry during a stint as backup vocalists in the funky local ensemble COOL TV.\nTheir current project dates back to 2012, when Loyva and Rembold got together as part of a larger ensemble. \u201cI thought I\u2019d make an all-woman supergroup,\u201d Loyva remembers. \u201cWe started with five, and then, after a couple of months and a couple of practices, we were down to two."}
```

One thing I did notice this morning is that if I print the dict before I sent it to the function send_to_api(), it has the unicode strings in it a la `u'my unicode string'`, but if I print the payload argument inside the send_to_api() function, it doesn't appear to be unicode anymore, like the source dictionary above:

```
{'description': 'The pair first collaborated when Loyva joined the lineup of Lost Lovers, and honed their chemistry during a stint as backup vocalists in the funky local ensemble COOL TV.\nTheir current project dates back to 2012, when Loyva and Rembold got together as part of a larger ensemble. \xe2\x80\x9cI thought I\xe2\x80\x99d make an all-woman supergroup,\xe2\x80\x9d Loyva remembers. \xe2\x80\x9cWe started with five, and then, after a couple of months and a couple of practices, we were down to two.'}
```

Comment: maybe `json_payload = json.dumps(payload.encode("utf8"))` ?

Comment: payload is the dict, so that's not going to work. thanks, though! i have also tried .encode("utf8") on the fields while building the dict.

Comment: For the record by the way, if I were to try to encode the unicode data going into the dict, it also wouldn't work (`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 727: ordinal not in range(128)`)

Comment: that means its already a byte string ... yeah I wasnt thinking earlier(wrt encoding a dict) :P

Comment: That's the odd thing— you'd think if it were already byte string and the characters are encoded correctly, that it would pass into base64 a-ok.

Comment: please provide a minimal example dict that causes this behaviour

Comment: @JoranBeasley, added in an example dict, thanks!

Comment: hmmm ... json dumps really wants to dump that as unicode ... maybe thats part of json spec? are you sure it doesnt work with the unicode characters encoded as unicode? (`eg "\\u00e2") can you add some prints to the code that recieves the post?

Comment: yeah, it seems like it wants to preserve it. the odd thing is when i POST the data to the server, the POST data is empty (with the unicode characters). i've checked the general $_REQUEST variable as well (PHP API). i'm not seeing any values on the access log, either. works great without those characters, though.

Comment: i actually tried bypassing the jason.dumps call as well, and just passing the dict directly to the pool.request() fields argument, without any additional luck, it's odd to say the least.

Comment: @JoranBeasley so I did just manage to get some POST output after a little more tinkering. I sent it without base64 encoding to test, and there's definitely some weird encoding issues going on. Everything on this end is set for UTF-8, and the server is as well. Getting garbage like so: `m??b?Ȧ?[Z??.?\???$ɩ݊w?rب???r۫??Z??h???zwe?{??Wy?'uh?v?????۫z?ay??v?????f❫b?zu??jwemjƭjf躸?z???X??֧q?+??ފ?Z????? b?׫?x,?{a??$??݂,?\?????*'y?ey?(~?????ʋ?j{f{??ʋ?j???M][??z????b???WZ?۶?W?Ƨ?%Z?W??m5u?޺???r?)?׫??z????b????-6(!????֧r+?+lrV??'-y?웡????%?y2D??ݻm5q)??Qb??.?M]?Ƭz??z??)buם??ei??N?{+h?M櫲????.qǬ?ǩj??z\???`

Comment: is the server running python? what if you print a repr? please try and use the same dictionary that you provided as an example.

Comment: the server is actually nginx/php-fpm. probably would have been simpler in the long run to make the API python as well. i would be curious to see what the output of that scenario would be, though.

Comment: surly there is a `bytes()` function. are you able to modify the server code? Im curious how you are decoding the POST data...  you could always just change it to hex encoded if you had to I guess ...

Comment: Yes, it does look like this has something to do with the base64 encode/decode. If I take that out of the equation the POST data shows up just fine.

Comment: Aha— I know what it is, it just wasn't obvious until I turned off the base64. The encoding is a coincidence; I didn't realize that json.dumps doesn't recurse through lists inside of dictionaries. It was a coincidence that those embedded lists were only occurring when the dictionary had extended characters in them. I'm surprised that json.dumps() wasn't throwing an exception. It was just making the entire string get mangled when it was sent to the server.